# Cannot find the "presenter view" check box in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I am using Office 365 which is provided by my work. The license is: "Office for the web (Education)". I want to present my powerpoint slide in a "presenter view". When I click the "Slide Show" I do not find this checkbox. According to a Microsoft [answer](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/video-use-presenter-view-fe7638e4-76fb-4349-8d81-5eb6679f49d7) about a similar question, I should find a checkbox there.

Can you explain how to use "presenter view" in Office 365 web edition? Is there any solution to this problem?

The Slide Show menu only has these options:

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn1gw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Presenter View is not supported on PowerPoint for web.

Please refer to "[Compare PowerPoint features on different platforms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-powerpoint-features-on-different-platforms-90986850-227c-4b25-938e-1c5838166b8b)"

[image]